# Signal Processing Quantisation

Tags: signals, signal-processing

Before we quantise a signal we prefer to first transform it into the frequency domain. Out of curiosity I am just wondering why we do that transformation?

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question! If you really want a nice and to-the-point answer, try to focus on something about this question that really stands out to you as confusing. A complete answer to the question that you are asking here quite nearly requires a comprehensive treatment of the basic tenants of signal processing, and that's not just a college course load. A comprehensive understanding of the real answer to *why* would probably require a Master's degree in the field of signal processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to keep my answer straight-forward and brief, including links to more detailed explanations where I think it is necessary.

1. **Encoding Information in a Transmitted Signal**

In order to appreciate the utility of frequency domain analysis over time domain analysis, you have to understand how information is... encoded, for lack of a better term ... into a transmitted signal. You might think to yourself, "How do you put data onto something like a beam of light or a radio wave?" Data is encoded into a signal by modulating some number of the signal's properties at some set rate. A pretty extensive explanation of this is given [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/84265). In my opinion, the easiest encoding scheme to understand visually is a binary one, like [On/Off Keying (OOK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying) - check out the graphic below, it's pretty much self-explanatory (full carrier = 1, no carrier = 0). Most of the different [digital encoding schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation#Digital_modulation_methods) are some form of ASK (Amplitude-Shift Keying), FSK (Frequency-Shift Keying), PSK (Phase-Shift Keying), CPM (Continuous Phase Modulation), ... etc. You see the pattern.

[image: Simple Graphic Showing On/Off Keying]

In fact, immediately after this you may wonder, "What is a beam of light or a radio wave? Are they different?" Light, which would mean visible light for us mere humans, and radio waves are both forms of electromagnetic radiation (which is quantized as photons). In fact, they are the same. They only differ by what frequency they oscillate at as they travel. A truly complete treatment of *this alone* would require an electro-magnetics course, paired with a quantum mechanics course to really drive home the physics piece of it. If digging into the nitty-gritty physical description of EM radiation interests you, you'll find further reading on the topic [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/254378).

2. **Appreciating the Frequency Content of a Signal**

Now, we understand that you can encode information into the frequency content of a signal. That should be pretty motivating in and of itself. In addition to that, viewing the frequency domain representation of a signal might reveal hidden information about the signal, like sources of noise (i.e., an errant peak in the frequency domain would indicate the frequency of the source of noise and allow you to design some sort of filter to remove that noise from your received signal). There's a [post on PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/advantage-of-frequency-domain-analysis.465418/#post-3096970) that goes into detail motivating this.

3. **Why Do We *Particularly* Love the *Fourier* Transform?**

Now, here is a subject that really would require a full class to teach. Joseph Fourier, a French scientist from the time of Napoleon, had the brilliant inclination to believe (and subsequently prove) that all signals can be decomposed into basic sinusoidal components. Each of these sinusoidal components has a specific frequency and amplitude. The amplitude tells you how "prevalent" that frequency is in your signal (i.e., a peak in the frequency representation of your signal means it's "prevalent). Thus, the Fourier Transform is a beautifully convenient way to take a signal that may look hopelessly complicated to parse in the time domain into a set of frequencies from which you can pick and choose which to pay attention to and which to ignore. **All in all, the frequency representation of a signal gives you insight into the frequencies that make up your signal as you see it in the time domain. In most cases, once you transform your signal into the frequency domain via the Fourier Transform, you will find clear peaks in the frequency domain to either filter out of your signal or analyze further.**

*Bonus: What is the difference between the FT and the DFT, FFT, etc.?*

Conceptually? None. In practice, the DFT and the FFT are just implementations that were designed to be more algorithmically efficient so that our fancy computers can perform the FT quicker on large datasets (because digital signals usually include thousands of samples)!

**Want More?**

If this hand-wavy explanation of mine doesn't suit your needs well enough, here is a [*very well laid-out* explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/70/16941) of why the Fourier Transform is such an important tool in the proverbial signal processing shed.